# Unable to get current logged in user id in subfolder of controller laravel5.6

Tags: laravel-5.6

Unable to get current logged in user id in subfolder of controller laravel5.6

In controller added

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
```

trying to get by using `Auth::user()->user_id;` but returns null

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class IndexController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        return Auth::user()->id;
    }
}
```

Comment: The question needs more clarity and permission levels attached to the controller.

Comment: In controller folder i have another folder called api, in api folder i have controller where i want current user id